# Check if Shiny app works correctly

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

I started to work with shiny. I wonder what a simple way is to reproduce the outcome which is not visualized and displayed in the app. Meaning, the stuff which runs in the background. Something like `print` when writing and debugging a little script.

So, I assigned a variable `test <- as.integer(1)` in the `server.R` file. When I open the console in Firefox and I want to print out my variable `test` it says its not defined. Am I doing something wrong with checking weather the variable is assigned or did I do something wrong during the assigning process?!

Comment: yeah just use `print`, make sure to `print` it in a `reactive` expression or in `observe` statement

Comment: @pops you mean something like `test <- reactive({input$bounds print(bounds)})`

Comment: Yeah something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not something like this

```
 test <- reactive({
      input$bounds 
      print(bounds)
  })
```

Rather something like:

```
 test <- reactive ({
       print(input$bounds)
 )}
```

or

```
 test <- reactive ({
      input$bounds
 )}
 observe ({
      print(test())
 )}
```

Comment: Yep, that works. You might wanna add `()` to test in your last example though. When something assigned in reactive, you need to call it as you would call a function. Otherwise it works.